# deactivate:unset:1: no such hash table element: pydoc

Tags: linux, shell, unix, zsh, pydoc

I am trying to setup my new laptop's development environment. After install zsh I am constantly getting error

> deactivate:unset:1: no such hash table element: pydoc

Please help. I have following simple aliases in my zshrc:

```
alias c="clear"
alias gpl="git pull"
alias gps="git push"
alias gc="git commit"
alias gck="git checkout"
alias d="git diff"
alias s="git status".
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can see [virtualenv pr on github](https://github.com/pypa/virtualenv/pull/843).

or you can change deactivate () function.

change `unset -f pydoc` to `unset -f pydoc >/dev/null 2>&1`

Comment: Where is the deactivate function located ? Where should I do the change you have suggested ?

Comment: Is this bug breaking functionality or we can still safely use it even with the error message?

Comment: @NamitaMaharanwar it's in `/path/to/your/envs/<your-env>/bin/activate`

Comment: Done. Thanks man! Can you explain the meaning of `unset -f pydoc >/dev/null 2>&1` ?

Comment: @NamitaMaharanwar  It's the means that both standard output and standard error redirect to /dev/null. Equivalent to hide error report.

Answer (score 1):

Try installing the latest version of virtualenv.

It's yet unreleased, but you can run this command to get it:

```
pip install https://github.com/pypa/virtualenv/tarball/develop
```

As for now the only change is this little fix. You can see the changelog [here](https://github.com/pypa/virtualenv/blob/develop/docs/changes.rst), and the files changed on that fix for reference are available [here](https://github.com/pypa/virtualenv/pull/843/files).

It's advised not to manually modify it, and install the forked version instead. (It's easier even)

Answer (score 0):

This error was present in released version of zsh. It's been fixed but yet not released. I have confirmed this on github. Follow this [link](https://github.com/pypa/virtualenv/blob/develop/docs/changes.rst).
Thanks!